# How are vector of class objects initialized

Tags: c++, vector

The code below has a class Screen. With members: position of cursor, width of screen, height of screen and contents of screen. It has another class Window_mgr which list is collection of screens. Each screen has a particular position in the vector. *I will mark out the line in code with an arrow so you need not to go through the complete code.*

My question is when we list initialise vector(suppose int) we simply do that by:

`std::vector<int> ivec{1, 2, 3, 4};`

But in the code below I am initialising vector of object type Screen. What does this means:

`VECTOR screens = VECTOR{ {Screen(24, 80, ' '), Screen(32, 56, 'r') }};`

I am talking only about the members inside of list initialisation. i.e. Screen(24, 80, ' ') and Screen(32, 56, 'r'). Do they call the version of constructor for Screen class? How is constructor called without creating object. According to me it should have been:

`{Screen sr1(24, 80, ' '), Screen sr2(32, 56, 'r')}`

Or just

`{(24, 80, ' '), (32, 56, 'r')}`

I did a search over internet but couldn't get the concept. Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Screen{
public:
    using pos = std::string::size_type; 

    Screen() = default; 
    Screen(pos ht, pos wd, char c) : 
        height(ht), width(wd), contents(ht *wd, c)  //in-class initializer
    {}

    char get() const { return contents[cursor]; }
    inline char get(pos ht, pos wd) const;

    Screen &set(char);
    Screen &set(pos, pos, char);

    Screen &move(pos r, pos c); 

    void some_member() const; 

private:
    pos cursor = 0; 
    pos height = 0, width = 0; 
    std::string contents; 
    mutable size_t access_ctr;
};


inline Screen &Screen::set(char c)
{
    contents[cursor] = c; 
    return *this; 
}

inline Screen &Screen::set(pos r, pos c, char ch)
{
    contents[r*width + c] = ch; 
    *this; 
}


void Screen::some_member() const
{
    ++access_ctr; 
}

inline Screen &Screen::move(pos r, pos c)
{
    pos row = r *width; 
    cursor = row + c; 
    return *this;
}

char Screen::get(pos r, pos c) const
{
    pos row = r * width;  
    return contents[row + c];
}    

//---------------------------------
class Window_mgr{
private:
    using VECTOR = std::vector<Screen> ;
    // A Window Manager has has one standard sized blank Screen
    VECTOR screens = VECTOR{ {Screen(24, 80, ' '), Screen(32, 56, 'r') }};  // <-----------------

};
//---------------------------------

int main()
{
    Screen scr{13, 33, 'c'};

    std::cout << scr.get(3, 1); 

    Window_mgr win{}; 


    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, it's perfectly valid to construct an instance of a class inline with a method call (essentially creating an anonymous instance of the class). So the syntax

```
VECTOR{ {Screen(24, 80, ' '), Screen(32, 56, 'r') }}
```

Is initializing a `VECTOR` with two instances of `Screen`. It also binds their lifecycle to that of the `VECTOR` without having to make a copy; they can be `move`'d safely since their scope is just the constructor call.

Comment: Yeah. In C++ that syntax creates a anonymous object on the spot. If we want to store it then need to give a object name otherwise not. In terms of vector that anonymous object becoming an element of that vector.